# What should I do if I have to declare a variable when I don't know the type for it?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code like this

```cpp
if (...) {
    const auto & h = std::make_shared<ClassB>();
    ... // here may be the function that uniquely belongs to ClassB
    ...
}
else (...) {
    const auto & h = std::make_shared<ClassC>();
    ... // here may be the function that uniquely belongs to ClassC
    ...
}
h->someFunction();
```

The last line of the above code is invalid because I use a variable that is declared inside the if-else clause.
To use `h` I have to declare it before the if-else clause.
But I can't because I don't know what type `h` belongs to before entering it.

<strike>I know I can declare it using ternary operator. But I don't want to because I think it will be redundant to have both ternary operator and if-else clause.</strike> Sorry, I can't. The compiler will complain "error: conditional expression is ambiguous;".

Are there any ways to keep only one if-else clause (no ternary operator) and I still can refer to h outside that if-else clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't [use a ternary operator]. The compiler will complain "error: conditional expression is ambiguous;".

You *can*, you just have to disambiguate the type of the result by casting one of the two expressions to a base class pointer:

```
auto const h = …
    ? init_class_b()
    : static_cast<std:unique_ptr<BaseClass>>(init_class_c());
```

Here, `init_class_*` are functions/lambdas which contain the body of your two `if` branches. That is, they create the object and run the unique functions on them. But as a point of code design, if such unique operations are needed, shouldn’t they go into the class constructors?

(Unlike in your code I haven’t made `h` a reference. Lifetime extension for const references is tricky and isn’t necessary here.)

Comment: How do you know that 'ClassB' and 'ClassC' have the same base class? Maybe they are just two template types that have the same method, no?

Comment: @Gupta I don’t *know* it given OP’s code and question it’s a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what the best approach is. You can declare `h` outside of your if-statement:

```
auto h = std::shared_ptr<SuperClass>{};  // is now nullptr

if (...) {
    h = std::make_shared<ClassB>
    ... // here may be the function that uniquely belongs to ClassB
    ...
}
else (...) {
    h = std::make_shared<ClassC>
    ... // here may be the function that uniquely belongs to ClassC
    ...
}
h->someFunction();
```

If ClassB and ClassC have no common super class that implements `someFunction`, this is impossible*. The compiler needs to have some type information to be able to generate the code.

*) Ok, there is `std::variant` and `std::any`, but at this level, you are not doing yourself a favor if you start going down this path. There are other approaches (e.g., static polymorphism aka. templates), too, but again, those are reserved for more special cases.

Comment: Agreed. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Depends on the usage. `std::variant` is often *superior* to subclass polymorphism. In fact, I’d say that for most uses it should be the default in modern C++, and subclass polymorphism should be reserved for very special cases.

Comment: This answer has the disadvantage that `h` can’t be made `const`. Using a ternary would be better, it just requires a disambiguating cast. Or use a lambda IIFE to initialise `h`.

Comment: ..or just a separate function that returns whatever is needed, construct from that, and let RVO handle the rest.

Comment: This is going more into the direction of best practices. Ternaries would become hard to read if there was a third option. It is also not said that the operations performed exclusively on ClassB are necessarily part of the initialization - they could also be regular operations. I modified my answer to clarify that this is one possible approach.

Comment: @mrks “Ternaries would become hard to read if there was a third option” — Absolutely not, look at my answer. Every new option just becomes an additional line of code, neatly arranged. In fact, I find ternaries rigorously the most readable solution for such cases. It highlights what’s happening here (dispatch the type of `h` depending on a condition`, whereas the `if` block contains a lot of syntactic noise which obfuscates this logic.